# Using groupby function to select different values from different column based on unique condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like:

```
PA  date    grade_conc  grade_rebar grade_mason grade_work  grade_timber    grade_steel grade_total
0   1   2018-10-13  A   NR  NR  NR  A   A   NR
1   1   2018-10-14  A   NR  NR  NR  A   Z   NR
2   1   2018-10-15  A   NR  NR  NR  B   U   NR
3   2   2018-10-13  B   NR  NR  NR  B   B   NR
4   2   2018-10-14  Z   NR  NR  NR  A   B   NR
5   2   2018-10-15  U   NR  NR  NR  B   A   NR
```

I want the result like:

```
   PA     date     grade_conc   grade_rebar grade_mason grade_work  grade_timber    grade_steel grade_total
    1   2018-10-15  A   NR  NR  NR  B   Z   NR
    2   2018-10-15  Z   NR  NR  NR  B   A   NR
```

The result should group by column `PA` and select latest date value for all the column except if the value of column is `U` in which case, it should be earlier date value where there is no `U`, only for that column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`replace` 'U' with `NaN` then you want the logic of `groupby` + `last`:

```
#df = df.sort_values(['PA', 'date'])
df.replace('U', np.NaN).groupby('PA').last()

          date grade_conc grade_rebar grade_mason grade_work grade_timber grade_steel grade_total
PA                                                                                               
1   2018-10-15          A          NR          NR         NR            B           Z          NR
2   2018-10-15          Z          NR          NR         NR            B           A          NR
```

Comment: Yeah, data sorting won't be a problem. Thanks, it's working

Comment: FYI `.last()` is deprecated since pandas 2.1.0

Comment: @smci That's DataFrame and Series.last(). groupby().last() is still here afaik.

Comment: @ALollz: oh. Confusing and not sure it's intentional to not also deprecate groupby().last(). I checked the doc and it's unclear.

Answer (score 2):

I am using `ffill` with `tail`

```
df = df.sort_values(['date'])
df=df.mask(df=='U')
df.groupby('PA').ffill().groupby('PA').tail(1)
Out[277]: 
   PA        date grade_conc     ...     grade_timber grade_steel grade_total
2   1  2018-10-15          A     ...                B           Z          NR
5   2  2018-10-15          Z     ...                B           A          NR
[2 rows x 9 columns]
```

Or `drop_duplicates`

```
df.groupby('PA').ffill().drop_duplicates('PA',keep='last')
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this using `groupby`, `apply`, `replace`, `ffill` and finally `tail`:

```
print(df.groupby('PA', as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.replace('U',np.nan).ffill().tail(1)))
```

Output:

```
     PA        date grade_conc grade_rebar grade_mason grade_work  \
0 2   1  2018-10-15          A          NR          NR         NR   
1 5   2  2018-10-15          Z          NR          NR         NR   

    grade_timber grade_steel grade_total  
0 2            B           Z          NR  
1 5            B           A          NR
```